# Cannot update files when submitting for the second time a form with ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to make a webpage that allows the user to submit a form, store it on a file, and later change the data and update the file. 
My problem is, the code works fine on the first time, and works fine loading the data from the file, but when submitting the form for the second time the php script doens't get any data. 
All this is made with ajax request and server side in php 
The code works as follows:

form.html:

//Tipical html form:

```
<form id="form" action="php/uploadInfo.php" method="POST">
  First name:<input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  Last name:<input type="text" name="lastname">
...
```

the AJAX:

```
$("#form").submit(function(form){
  form.preventDefault();
  var form = $("#form").serialize();
  $.post($("#form").attr('action'),form, function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

php file:

```
if (isset($_POST['firstname'])){
  //Do stuff
}
```

This works fine at first time 
Then i get store the data and later i have no problem getting the data and filling the form with it 
But if i try to submit:

```
if (isset($_POST['firstname'])){
```

firstname is not set, but the ajax request is successful the php script runs.
i made a test, if the php script is like:

```
<? echo "First Name: $_POST['firstname'] , Last Name: $_POST['lastname']" ?>
```

the first time it runs i get something like: 
  First Name: John , Last Name: Doe 
and in the second time 
  First Name: , Last Name:

**Found the problem**  
When i filled the from with data i disabled firstname input and lastname so user couldn't change that, and apparently that didn't when submit.

Comment: Add 'console.log(form);' under 'var form ...' and check what content it has on second submition

Comment: I already tested that. I'm always testing what's in and out. And btw i found the solution, the problem was that i desabled the the First Name and Last name input so the user couldn't change that and apparently that didn't went submited with the rest of the form, but now is ok